# Is there a way to force print!/println! to use a Windows new line (CR LF)

Tags: rust

I am using Rust 1.9 on Windows 10. When playing with some code and comparing the result captured from standard output, I noticed that output uses a Linux line ending 0x0A (10, LF) rather than windows 0x0D 0x0A (13 10, CR LF). I tried following:

```
println!("{} or {}  = {}", a, b, a | b);

print!("{} or {}  = {}\n", a, b, a | b);
```

Is there a way to force Windows line endings?

Comment: Anything against `print!("{} or {} = {} \r\n", a, b, a | b);`?

Comment: The `println!` macro [doesn't do any checks for the environment](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/libstd/macros.rs#L118) when it adds the new line unfortunately. So there doesn't seem to be a flag you can set to make it all work as you expect. I'd say manually calling `print!` as above is your best bet.

Comment: Yeah \r\n does the trick. Thanks, I should have thought of that. Please make it an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead FYI, hit `y` on GitHub to change the url to a permalink that contains the git hash. `master` is likely to rot over time You can also insert a tag in place of `master` (my preferred route). Also, shift-clicking allows you to link to a range of lines.

Comment: Wow thanks @Shepmaster - I had often thought there must be a better way to link to lines but I never bothered to read the GH docs. I will remember this from now on... thanks!

Comment: If I run `app > file.txt` from powershell, the line endings get converted to windows-style automagically :)

Comment: The conversion should probably be on a lower level than the `println!` macros, when writing files in text mode (like in C): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#In_programming_languages

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you check out [the implementation of `println!`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.9.0/src/libstd/macros.rs#L116-L121), it's pretty straight-forward:

```
macro_rules! println {
    ($fmt:expr) => (print!(concat!($fmt, "\n")));
    ($fmt:expr, $($arg:tt)*) => (print!(concat!($fmt, "\n"), $($arg)*));
}
```

You can copy-paste-modify this to replace `\n` with `\r\n`:

```
macro_rules! wprintln {
    ($fmt:expr) => (print!(concat!($fmt, "\r\n")));
    ($fmt:expr, $($arg:tt)*) => (print!(concat!($fmt, "\r\n"), $($arg)*));
}
```

Comment: Do you know whether this is intentional or not? I could perfectly imagine a `cfg` attribute to switch the implementation of `println` but I seem to recall a discussion where having platform-specific behavior was seen as a source of portability issues...

Comment: @MatthieuM. I am unaware of any discussion, sadly. Personally I prefer having a single behavior across platforms.