# In Rust, is there a way to make literal newlines in r###"..."### using Windows convention?

Tags: string, rust, newline, heredoc, rawstring

I'm using Rust on Windows and I found

```
r###"abc
def"###
```

results in a string `abc\ndef`. Is there an easy way to make it `abc\r\ndef`? Or must I do the replacement manually?

Comment: Does your source file actually contain CR LF characters inside that string?

Comment: How about: `.replace("\n", "\r\n")` and see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37558353/is-there-a-way-to-force-print-println-to-use-a-windows-new-line-cr-lf)

Comment: @JonasBerlin Yes, I'm sure about it.

Comment: If you urgently need this `'\r'`, you could insert one at the end of the first line, so that two of them are in the file. Provided your editor can do this. :-P

Comment: The compiler [translates both `\r\n` and `\n` in a string liteal to just `\n` in the resulting string](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/tokens.html#string-literals). This prevents an invisible difference in the source code from changing the semantics of the code. If you want Windows line endings, you need to translate them yourself, as commented above.

Comment: @SvenMarnach That is the section for `String literals`. In the section for `Raw string literals` there is nothing about translation from `\r\n` to `\n`. On the contrary it says "The raw string body can contain any sequence of Unicode characters" and "All Unicode characters contained in the raw string body represent themselves". 

I think the documentation should be fixed. The behavior can not be changed as lots of software would be affected.

Comment: @HHK @sven literally just linked to the documentation that clearly mentions how this works: “A line-break is either a newline (`U+000A`) or a pair of carriage return and newline (`U+000D`, `U+000A`). Both byte sequences are normally translated to `U+000A`[…]”.

Comment: @mcarton Once more: You are quoting from the text for "String literals" while the text from the "Raw string literals" subsection applies here. See also [this issue for the reference documentation](https://github.com/rust-lang/reference/issues/626) which mentions that the documentation on CRLF translation of raw strings needs to be updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Rust compiler converts all CRLF sequences to LF when reading source files since 2019 (see [merge request](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/62948), [issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/62865)) and there is no way to change this behavior.

What you can do:

1. Use `.replace("\n", "\r\n")` at runtime to create a new `String` with CRLF line terminators.
2. Use regular instead of raw string literals and end your lines with `\r`, e.g.

   ```rust
   "abc\r
   def"
   ```
3. Use the [`std::include_str!()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.include_str.html) macro to include a file in UTF-8 format which contains the text with CRLF line terminators.